# Variable inside the link

Tags: php

Would someone be able to help me with some php.
I am new to this and I am trying to solve the puzzle.

I am trying to combine the input data that user has provided with the link so that final output displays record for the user whose regid was provided by user via input text field.

Here is some code I came up with that obviously does not work.

```php
class Fields_View_Helper_FieldStats extends Fields_View_Helper_FieldAbstract
{
  public function fieldStats($subject, $field, $value)
  {
    $userid = preg_replace(trim($value->value));

    // create user's profile address using their username/userid
    $stats = $userid;

    echo '<div style="margin:0px auto;"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://e1.statsheet.com/embed/';
    return $this->view->string()->chunk($value->value);
    echo '/1/NuNes.js"></script></div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you `return`ing before you've completed your `echo`?

Comment: change `return` to `echo` and explain what result you need, maybe also why do you need $userid and $stats variables, they are not used?

Comment: That is where my problem is. I don't know how I can connect these three lines together :(

Comment: Ilya Bursov, basically, when user register he/she provides a number that than stored and inputed inside the link. When rendered the output should be a table with returned values for that user.  $stats = $userid; this capture the number from the input text field but I don't know how to include that variable inside the link :()

Comment: use the . operator that concatenates fields.

Comment: "." Will connect them, though a simple variable would be more readable.

Comment: OMG, Pete Scott!!! It worked!!!

Comment: Guys, you are awesome!!! I thank you all so so much. I've been banging my head with this thing for quite some time now :((( Huge thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate a string in PHP do this (note the periods, which are doing the work)

```
$str = "Line 1 " . $somevar . " Line 2";
return $str
```

Issuing a `return` terminates your function. I would build one string inside a variable then return that variable

Answer (score 1):

The `return` ends the method, because it returns the value to the caller.

```
<?php

function fn() {
  return "bar";
}

echo fn(); // will output bar

function fn2() {
  echo "foo";
  return "bar";
}

echo fn2(); // will output foobar

function fn3() {
  return "foo" . fn();
}

echo fn3(); // will output foobar as well

?>
```

And here's how you can connect those three lines in the code snippet you posted:

```
<?php
class Fields_View_Helper_FieldStats extends Fields_View_Helper_FieldAbstract
{
  public function fieldStats($subject, $field, $value)
  {
    $userid = preg_replace(trim($value->value));

    // create user's profile address using their username/userid
    $stats = $userid;

    return
      '<div style="margin:0px auto;"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://e1.statsheet.com/embed/' .
        $this->view->string()->chunk($value->value) .
      '/1/NuNes.js"></script></div>'
    ;
  }
}

?>
```

And here's how you can concatenate strings:

```
<?php

$string1 = 'foo ' . fn() . ' bar';

$string2 = "foo 2" . fn() . " bar";

?>
```

And here's how you can embed stuff in variables (faster):

```
<?php

$string1 = fn();
$string1 = "foo {$string1} bar";

// Or with an object
class Foo {
  public function fn(){}
}
$foo = new Foo();
$string1 = "foo {$foo->fn()} bar";

?>
```